# CollapseGroup Angular 2 Kendo Grid

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, grouping

I want to collapse the grouped rows on a button click. I tried the following code.

```
    @ViewChild(GridComponent) grid: GridComponent;
       close(); {
       for (let m = 0; m < 5; m = m + 1) {
          this.grid.groupCollapse(m.toString());
       }
    }
```

but I get a compilation error saying "Declaration expected." I have imported ***GridComponent*** as well. Can somebody help on this?

I tried this way as well;

```
    public collapseRows(grid: GridComponent): void {
       for (let m = 0; m < 5; m = m + 1) {
          grid.collapseGroup(m.toString());
       }
    }
```

I cannot get the value for the grid. Its "*undefined*". How to pass the "grid" to this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the Grid can be obtained either ViewChild:

```
<button class="k-button" (click)="collapseGroups()">Collapse All</button>
<br /><br />
<kendo-grid #grid...

@ViewChild('grid') private grid;
...     
public collapseGroups() {
// loop through the groups of the groped data and call closeGroup() for each group
this.gridView.data.forEach((gr, idx) => this.grid.collapseGroup(idx.toString()));
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/9LBMHuvS5eAWbUj1MBQg?p=preview)

... or via passing the template reference variable to the custom method directly:

```
<button class="k-button" (click)="collapseGroups(grid)">Collapse All</button>
<br /><br />
<kendo-grid #grid
...        >
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/FlBUyGUUZCQpZAd2qosC?p=preview)